# Google search keyword in google tag manager variable

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-search

Is it possible to pull the google search keyword that brought a person to the landing page into the GTM variable? Thinking it must be somewhere in the payload?

Answer (score 1):

Google stopped sending organic search keywords some time ago, so there is nothing in the payload you can use.

This was during the general migration to encrypted (ssl) connections (not too long ago ssl/tls was used only on payment pages and the like) and IIRC Google said that removing that info from the search referrer was a security measure to prevent data leaks when moving from secure search to potentially insecure sites or something like it).

So since there is no information on organic search keywords, you cannot get it from within GTM. For ads you can add the matching keyword (i.e. the keyword that triggered the ad, not what the user actually typed) via v[alue track  parameters](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6305348?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-or-edit-a-tracking-template-with-valuetrack-parameters-at-the-campaign-level%2Cfinal-url-tracking-template-or-custom-parameter) to you destinantion url and get it from there.